# Hide the word 'category' from my permalinks

Tags: categories, permalinks

How can I hide the word 'category' from my permalinks?

[image: image showing category in permalink]

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this WP Plugin called [No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)

Comment: thank you for your answer but I need any code for that not plugin

Comment: @Abu Adam - Why is a plugin not suitable? If you want code then take the plugin apart and apply how you want.